# If actual date is Friday, also show rows at saturday and sunday Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, date, weekend

Normally I only show a record, if the actual date is one year later than the date in the database. How can I check if that day is a friday and then show also the records with the date of the saturday or sunday?

For example: Friday the 13th before one year. I will also show records from 14th(saturday) and 15th(sunday)

```
where myDate.arrival < TRUNC (SYSDATE) -365)
```

That's my actual statement.

Comment: case statement? user defined function? query against a weekends table? you need to provide more info.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was wrong. I've added some informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where Mydate.Arrival < Trunc (Sysdate) - 365
Or (to_char(Mydate.Arrival, 'D') = 6 AND Mydate.Arrival < Trunc (Sysdate) -363)
```

This way, you can check if that day is a Friday (6th day of week) and then select records whose Arrival value is less than sysdate - 363 (2 more days - Saturday and Sunday - included).

Comment: Thx. I will try this and will accept the answer as soon as it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need a condition in case. Check the example below for reference:

```
WHERE txnday in 
  CASE to_char(sysdate, 'Day')
      WHEN 'Friday' THEN // Include condition for Sat and Sun as well
      ELSE // Include condition for only that day
  END
```